# Delphi: MySql with Indy10

Tags: mysql, delphi, indy10

I am looking for a component which is thread safe and can be used with indy10 TcpServer. Can anyone points me in a direction. i searched over and found a topic here in stackoverflow and a guy suggested [mysql.pas](http://www.audio-data.de/delphi/mysql/mysql.zip)

is it safe to use with multi-threaded applications?

sorry for being so noobish

Comment: It would be most helpful if you would include a link to the quetion here on SO where that particular file is recommended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [what I think is the homepage of that particular piece of software](http://www.audio-data.de/mysql.html) it is just an interface to libmysql.dll and that one can be safely used in a multithreaded context as long as each thread uses its own connection according to [this source](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/8680) that looks [quite authorative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Widenius)

Comment: Thanks, so a separate connection to database for each client.

Comment: @JunaidNoor what is here related to Indy TcpServer?

Comment: I just thought i should tell where i will be using it